# Subtracting two cells which move each month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to subtract two cells to show movement in the month as figures provided are year to date.

As each month new column is added, the formula needs to update to reflect the movement in the current month, i.e. in January I need to subtract `B12`-`A12`, in Feb `C12`-`B12`, in Mar `D12`-`C12` and so on. The formula stays in the same cell the whole time.

Is there a way to have a formula that would automatically update each month or do I have to manually update it each month?

Comment: Have you tried combining the month function with the date or today function to get the required offsets?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample of how your sheet looks and where/what outcome you want to see

Comment: [edit] your post and add some sample data , also whether you are using month name or something difference, please b specific to avoid down vote !!

Answer (score 0):

The TODAY function can be used to obtain the current date

```
=TODAY()
```

The MONTH function can be used to get the current month from TODAY()

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

The OFFSET function can be used to "Return a reference to a range that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells. The reference that is returned can be a single cell or a range of cells.".

```
=OFFSET(REFERENCE CELL, ROW, COLUMNS, HEIGHT, WIDTH)
```

The range values height and width are optional and in this case not required.

Your first CELL A12 can be you reference cell and you are looking to select the your first argument in the sum from the column the number of the month to the right of the reference cell. JANUARY is column 2 and JUNE column 7 which is 6 cells to the right of reference column 1, that is:

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

Your second argument the one you want to subtract is then MAY and is 5 cells to the right of reference cell

```
=MONTH(TODAY())-1
```

therefore the calculation needs to be sum of refernce A12, Current row  (0 for no offset), column offsets with the above argument offsets.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A12,0,MONTH(TODAY())),-(OFFSET(A12,0,(MONTH(TODAY())-1))))
```

If you want the date to be less volatile or automatic you can substitute TODAY() for a period date reference within your spreadsheet.

Comment: Might be better to use INDEX as OFFSET is a [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-volatile) formula.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer based on the **Index** function

The TODAY function can be used to obtain the current date

```
=TODAY()
```

The MONTH function can be used to get the current month from TODAY()

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

Returns the value of an element in a table or an array, selected by the row and column number indexes.

***INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])***

Your first CELL A12 can be your array starting point and assuming 12 months the array end point will be M12, you are looking to select the your first argument in the sum from the column the number of the month to the right of your reference cell. JANUARY is column 2 and seventh month JULY is column 8 which is 7 cells to the right of reference cell in column 1, that is:

```
=MONTH(TODAY())+1
```

Your second argument the one you want to subtract is then JUNE and is 6 cells to the right of reference cell

```
=MONTH(TODAY())
```

therefore the calculation needs to be the value of cell in array A12:M12 in current row (0) with column number based on month today plus 1 then subtract the value of cell in array A12:M12 in current row (0) with column number based on month today.

```
=INDEX(A12:M12,0,MONTH(TODAY())+1)-INDEX(A12:M12,0,MONTH(TODAY()))
```